# autodesk forge extract geometry RVT -> OBJ results in bad request error

Tags: java, extract, autodesk-forge

I am trying to extract geometry of selected objects in viewer to a separate model. For that I try following https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/extract-geometry-from-source-file/. But I get a "400 bad request" error when trying to perform post job and can't figure what could be wrong.
My code for JobPayload creation and javascript for calling are given bellow. As far as I saw other questions, people did extraction to OBJ from revit file, but according https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/ it should be possible only to do RVT to SVF. So is it possible to extract geometry from revit file or should I change it to another type? Another question is if it's possible to use svf for extraction?

```
    private JobPayload extractGeometryToOBJ(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            JobPayload job = new JobPayload();

            JobPayloadInput input = new JobPayloadInput();
            JSONObject inputObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("input");
            input.setUrn(inputObj.getString("urn"));

            JobObjOutputPayloadAdvanced advanced = new JobObjOutputPayloadAdvanced();
            advanced.setExportFileStructure(ExportFileStructureEnum.SINGLE);
            JSONObject advancedFormat = (JSONObject) jsonObject.getJSONObject("output").getJSONArray("formats").get(0);
            JSONObject advancedFormatInfo = advancedFormat.getJSONObject("advanced");
            JSONArray objectIds = advancedFormatInfo.getJSONArray("objectIds");

            List objectIdList = new ArrayList();
            objectIds.forEach(e -> objectIdList.add(Integer.toString((Integer) e)));

            advanced.setModelGuid(advancedFormatInfo.getString("modelGuid"));
            advanced.setObjectIds(objectIdList);

            JobPayloadItem formats = new JobPayloadItem();
            formats.setAdvanced(advanced);
            formats.setType(JobPayloadItem.TypeEnum.OBJ);
            formats.setViews(Arrays.asList(JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._3D));

            JobPayloadOutput output = new JobPayloadOutput();
            output.setFormats(Arrays.asList(formats));

            job.setInput(input);
            job.setOutput(output);
            return job;
        }
```

```
    function getObjects(objectIds, modelGuid) { 
        getForgeToken(function (access_token) {
            var urn = viewerApp.myDocument.myData.urn;
            jQuery.post({
                url: '/api/forge/modelderivative/jobs',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                        "actionType": "extractToOBJ",
                       "input": {
                           "urn": urn
                        },
                        "output": {
                            "formats": [{
                                 "type": "obj",
                                 "advanced": {
                                     "modelGuid": modelGuid,
                                     "objectIds": objectIds
                                 }
                            }]
                    }}),
                    success: function (res) {
                           console.log(res);
                       },
                       error: function (err) {
                           console.log(err);
                       }
              })}, "internal")
    }
```

Comment: Job config for `Geometry Extract` doesn't need this line `formats.setViews(Arrays.asList(JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._3D));`

Comment: And yes, `Geometry Extract` can be used to RVT files, haven't you tired to call API without Forge SDK? **Note.** before doing `Geometry Extract`, you have to wait for the SVF translation completely.

Comment: This might also be related to your `objectIds` input, please check~